# What are these spots on my butternut squash?

Tags: food-safety, squash

I just roasted a bunch of butternut squash for dinner and am getting to puree, but am noticing that some of the pieces have weird glue-looking spots.  It sort of looks like when water weeps out of the pores on the squash, only it's white and the consistency of silly putty.  They're very small spots (like the size of a straight pin head), and close to the skin on the flesh, on the cross-section.  I feel like I'm describing this poorly. Here's a picture:

[image: squash]

**My question**: Is this stuff safe to eat, or do I need to compost it and find something else for dinner?  I'd rather not give my whole family food poisoning!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen those before when I have cooked squash; they seem more common when I microwave it. I *suspect* they are just starchy deposits. I have always just wiped them off and eaten it anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I think we'll give it a go. We were mostly curious because they are firm--almost seed-like.

Comment: I don't know if that's what it was but we ate it and it was delicious.

Comment: Thanks for posting this you guys.  We just pulled our pre sliced squash out of the fridge and they had these.  We're going ahead with eating them.